# How can I use a class made in PHP?

Tags: php, oop

I have a ready made PHP class.
Now how can I use that class or implement it in my page.
How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Do you just want to know how to include a class file? Or do you need to know how to instantiate an instance of the class? If you could provide more detail it would be very helpful.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_science%29#PHP

Comment: You can create an object/instance, and call functions from it/set properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your class by calling it in the following ways:

```
$var = new ClassName;  # create object (construct)
$var->methods();       # access a method (call)
$var->publicVars;      # access a property
```

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a bit vague, but you first need to have that class "visible" from your script, which is generally done using [`require_once`](http://php.net/require_once) to "include" the file containing your class.

Then, you can instanciate your class :

```
$my_object = new MyClass();
```

And, then, you can call its methods :

```
$my_object->myMethod($param);
```

Don't hesitate to go through the related pages in the PHP manual : [Classes and Objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) ; it'll cover some basic grounds, which will help you a lot ;-)

Answer (score 2):

For the details you will have to provide the actual class or, even better, check the documentation that hopefully came with this class. For a general tutorial on how to use classes in PHP you might want to take a look at the [official documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)

Answer (score 1):

In your php page, you need to include the class:

```
<?php require_once("path/to/your/class/ClassName.class.php") ?>
```

And then you need to initialise it:

```
$classVariableName = new ClassName;

$classVariableName->foo('bar');
```

Hope that helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$classInstance = new ClassName();
$classInstance->methodName();
```

some basics [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php)